# Return datetime from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetWhenTaskLastRun]   
    @dt datetime out         
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        @dt = whenTaskLastRan
    FROM
        [dbo].[t_whenTaskLastRan]   
END
```

and this C# code to execute this query:

```
SqlDataReader reader;

string ConnectionString = SafaConnectionString.ConnectionString;

SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetWhenTaskLastRun", Connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters["@dt"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

try
{
    Connection.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
        return (DateTime)cmd.Parameters["@dt"].Value;
    else
        return DateTime.Now;
}
```

but it always returns `reader.HasRows = false` and no records.

Have I got the query wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stored procedure is not returning a result set; it's only assigning the output parameter value.  Use the `ExecuteNonQuery` method instead.  The output parameter will be `NULL` if no rows qualify or the column value is `NULL`.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (cmd.Parameters["@dt"].Value == DBNull.Value)      
    return (DateTime)cmd.Parameters["@dt"].Value;
else
    return DateTime.Now;
```